# Pick random directory from plist in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, random, plist

I have class like this below to pick questions from plist, but now I want to take them in random order

```
class QuizLoader {

public func loadSimpleQuiz(forQuiz guizName: String) throws -> [SimpleQuestion] {
    var questions = [SimpleQuestion]()
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: guizName, ofType: "plist") {
        if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
            let tempArray: Array = dict["Questions"]! as! [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]
            for dictionary in tempArray {
                let questionToAdd = SimpleQuestion(question: dictionary["Question"] as! String, correctAnswer: dictionary["CorrectAnswer"] as! String)


            }

            return questions

        } else {
            throw LoaderError.dictionaryField
        }

    } else {
        throw LoaderError.pathField
    }
}
```

I was trying to do this with this [hint](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-i-randomize-dictionaries-instead-of-arrays-swift) but I have error with `var unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(quoteDictionary.count)`

I have already spend few hours trying to figure it out, but still no luck.

```
    func loadQuestions() {

    do {
        questionArray = try quizeLoader.loadMultipleChoiceQuiz(forQuiz: "MultipleChoice")
        loadNextQuestion()
    } catch  {
        switch error {
        case LoaderError.dictionaryField:
            print("Could not load directory")
        case LoaderError.pathField:
            print("Cound not find valid file at path")
        default:
            print("Unknown error")
        }
    }


}


func loadNextQuestion() {
    currentQuestion = questionArray[questionIndex]
    setTitleForButtons()
}
```

Comment: The `questions` variable would remain empty is your snippet of code. Are you sure you posted the correct code for us to check? Can you elaborate on how did you attempt to randomize things (referred to in the `hint` link)?

Comment: Yes im sure that code to check is correct. Func takes content form dictionary Questions one by one (item-0 > item-1 and so one). At this point i want to randomise picking questions from this dictionary.

Comment: @MarwanAlani i have edited my code, maybe now you can help me